# Restrict the zoom while clicking on the GeoJSON in folium

Tags: python, leaflet, maps, folium

I made a map displaying all Polygons as GeoJSON's and did not use the Choropleth map. I also added a tooltip for each GeoJSON polygon and forbade zooming and padding. However, the problem occurs when I click on polygon and it automatically zooms. How can I restrict the zoom while clicking on the GeoJSON in folium?

This is how I add them:

```
    m=folium.Map([55.4152363,50.8576256],zoom_start=7,zoom_control=False,
                   scrollWheelZoom=False,
                    max_zoom=6,
                    min_zoom=6,
                   dragging=False)
   


folium.GeoJson(final_data[["district","geometry","Covid_Cases","Color"]].to_json(),
    style_function=lambda x: {'fillColor':x["properties"]["Color"],'fillOpacity': 0.9, 'opacity': 0.7},
    highlight_function=lambda x: {"fillOpacity": 0.3, "opacity": 0.3},
    tooltip=folium.features.GeoJsonTooltip(fields=["district","Covid_Cases"],aliases=["Район:","Cases:"])).add_to(m)
```

[image]

Comment: Please show us the code that displays the polygons. Without seeing it, it is difficult to figure out how the problem can be solved.

Comment: This will be in the upcoming v0.12 release. It will have a `zoom_on_click` option for `GeoJson` that will be `False` by default.